# Changing video in jwplayer on error

Tags: jwplayer

I'd like the jwplayer to load a different video every time there is an error.
I tried

```
 jwplayer().onError(function(e){                                        
                setTimeout(function(){                 
                    jwplayer().stop();
                    var errorVideo="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4";
                    jwplayer().setup({
                        file: errorVideo,
                        height: 360,
                        width: 640,
                        autostart:true
                    }).load();
                }, 1000);               
            }
```

And I can hear the audio but can't see the video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `jwplayer().remove()` to get rid of the old video before calling `jwplayer().setup()` with the new video.

Comment: That did it , Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.load()` instead of `.setup()`. This will load a new file into your existing player instead of creating a new player with conflicting JS.

Here's a demo of this functionality with a code sample: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/basic/custom-error/

Comment: load() will take a RSS/JSON URL, or you can also pass a whole new playlist: {} block. Please see https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/api/javascript_api_reference/ for more details.